# Как объединить поля в таблице по времени?

Tags: sql, sqlite

есть таблица, в ней несколько полей, в том числе и время есть, которое спокойно вычисляется с помощью функции  datetime() и похожих.
как мне группировать по времени (по 5 минут)?
то есть результат: первые 5 минут - столько-то кол-во данных, вторые - столько-то ...
использую sqlite

Comment: Группируйте по (схематично) `ЦелаяЧасть((ДатаВремяЗаписи - MIN(ДатаВремяПоВсейТаблице))/5)`.

Comment: @Akina, немного не понял, по крайне мере про целую часть...

Comment: Разность между минимальным временем в таблице и временем записи - это понятно? берём в минутах, делим на 5 и отбрасываем дробную часть. Для записей от минимума и до минимум+5 минут это будет ноль, для следующих 5 минут - единица, потом два, три... вполне пригодно для группировки.